# Map multiple columns using Series from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames. I need is to replace the text in columns `B`, `C`, and `D` in `df1` with the values from `df2['SC']`, based on the value of `df2['Title']`.

> df1

```
A     B      C      D
Dave  Green  Blue   Yellow
Pete  Red
Phil  Purple
```

> df2

```
  A     ID   N    SC     Title
  Dave  1    5      2    Green
  Dave  1    10     2    Blue    
  Dave  1    15     3    Yellow
  Pete  2    100    3    Red
  Phil  3    200    4    Purple
```

> Desired output:

```
 A     B     C      D    
 Dave  2     2     3
 Pete  3
 Phil  4
```

Comment: Also matching on 'A'? What happens if both Dave and Phil have 'Green' or is that never a possibility?

Comment: @ALollz That's a good point and I failed to mention that... Actually I think the below solution just flagged that issue as 'InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `stack` + `map` + `unstack`

```
df1.set_index('A').stack().map(df2.set_index('Title')['SC']).unstack()
```

```
        B    C    D
A
Dave  2.0  2.0  3.0
Pete  3.0  NaN  NaN
Phil  4.0  NaN  NaN
```

---

If a column contains *all* `NaN` it will be lost.  To avoid this you could `reindex`

```
.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)             # append to previous command
```

Comment: I realise 'Title' is not necessarily unique to a Name (A) which I think causes the following   - 'InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects -- The SC will always be matched to a Title however, it's just that they could both appear more than once against different values in A